# Sql query to select the records for past 60 seconds and compare the temperature of the selected records and if any record has higher value then ignore

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-arithmetic

I am trying to eliminate the data anomalies in the data I am receiving from eventhub and send only selected data to azure functions through Azure stream analytics for that I am writing a sql query where I need some help

Requirement:  I need to collect the past 60 seconds data and need to group by Id and compare the records that I received in the 60 seconds and If any record value is way higher than the selected values than ignore that record (for example, I will collect the 4 records in past 60 seconds and if the data is  40 40 40 40 5. We should drop the 5. Example 2 - 20 20 20 500 drop the 500. ).

My sql table will be something like this:

```
id  Temp    date    datetime
123 30  2023-01-01  2023-01-01 12:00:00
124 35  2023-01-01  2023-01-01 12:00:00
123 31  2023-01-01  2023-01-01 12:00:00
123 33  2023-01-01  2023-01-01 12:00:00
123 60  2023-01-01  2023-01-01 12:00:00
124 36  2023-01-01  2023-01-01 12:00:00
124 36  2023-01-01  2023-01-01 12:00:00
124 8   2023-01-01  2023-01-01 12:00:00
124 36  2023-01-01  2023-01-01 12:00:00
```

I need to eliminate the records that are not in the range with the other records

Comment: Do you have a definition of what sort of variance/deviation should be accounted for? More than 1 standard deviations? 1.5? These are things you have to determine before your question can be answered effectively

Comment: Side note: I'm not sure whether or not Temp refers to temperature or some other value that may approach or go below zero. If it is, consider your criteria carefully, so that small changes when near zero are not considered to be wildly high or infinite fluctuations. Also consider what to do at the start of the data when there is insufficient prior data to reliably compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave the details of the comparison up to you, but you can use a `CROSS APPLY` to gather the data for comparison.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TemperatureData T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT AVG(T2.Temp * 1.0) AS PriorAvgTemp, COUNT(*) As PriorCount
    FROM TemperatureData T2
    WHERE T2.id = T.id
    AND T2.datetime >= DATEADD(second, -60, T.datetime)
    AND T2.datetime < T.datetime
) P
WHERE T.Temp BETWEEN P.PriorAvgTemp - 10 AND P.PriorAvgTemp + 10
--OR P.PriorCount < 3 -- Should we allow if there is insufficient prior data
--AND P.PriorCount >= 3 -- Should we omit if there is insufficient prior data
```

Be sure you have an index on `TemperatureData(id, datetime)`.

If you are willing to accept the last N values instead of a time range, windowed aggregate calculation may be more efficient.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        AVG(T.Temp * 1.0)
            OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY datetime
                 ROWS BETWEEN 60 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
            AS PriorAvgTemp,
        COUNT(*) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY datetime
                 ROWS BETWEEN 60 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
            AS PriorCount
    FROM TemperatureData T
) TT
WHERE TT.Temp BETWEEN TT.PriorAvgTemp - 10 AND TT.PriorAvgTemp + 10
--OR TT.PriorCount < 3 -- Should we allow if there is insufficient prior data
--AND TT.PriorCount >= 3 -- Should we omit if there is insufficient prior data
```

Please note: The above is untested code, which may need some syntax fixes and debugging. If you discover errors, please comment and I will correct the post.

Comment: @T N sorry for the late reply but I am able use the query that you posted and with small modifications I got that working. Thank you so much for your help